# I've encountered an error converting an integer to text in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, date, numbers, integer

Everything on my HTML code is working just fine apart from a JavaScript error I am getting. Whenever I try to convert an integer such as the current day, it defaults to the highest possible value.

I always get a value of "Aujourd’hui c’est samedi, le trente–et–un décembre, 2015" when I run this:

```html
<html>
<title>
  French Review - Time and Dates
</title>

<head>
  <style>
    div.img {
      margin: 5px;
      padding: 5px;
      border: 1px solid #0000ff;
      height: auto;
      width: auto;
      float: left;
      text-align: center;
    }
    div.img img {
      display: inline;
      margin: 5px;
      border: 1px solid #ffffff;
    }
    div.img a:hover img {
      border: 1px solid #0000ff;
    }
    p {
      font-weight: normal;
      font-family: Verdana;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <center>
    <img src="Header.png" width=1250></img>

    <div class="img">
      <img src="10-30.png" alt="10:30 AM" width="220">
      <p id="answer">Quelle heure est-il?</p>
      <button type="button" onclick="document.getElementById('answer').innerHTML = 'Il est dix heure et demie du matin.'">
        Reveal answer</button>
    </div>

    <div class="img">
      <img src="1-15.png" alt="1:15 PM" width="220">
      <p id="answer2">Quelle heure est-il?</p>
      <button type="button" onclick="document.getElementById('answer2').innerHTML = 'Il est une heure et quart du l&#8217;après-midi.'">
        Reveal answer</button>
    </div>

    <div class="img">
      <img src="5-45.png" alt="5:45 PM" width="220">
      <p id="answer3">Quelle heure est-il?</p>
      <button type="button" onclick="document.getElementById('answer3').innerHTML = 'Il est six heure moins le quart.'">
        Reveal answer</button>
    </div>

    <div class="img">
      <img src="12-00.png" alt="12:00 AM" width="220">
      <p id="answer4">Quelle heure est-il?</p>
      <button type="button" onclick="document.getElementById('answer4').innerHTML = 'Il est midi.'">
        Reveal answer</button>
    </div>

    <br>
    <br>
    <br>
    <br>
    <br>
    <br>
    <br>
    <br>
    <br>
    <br>
    <br>
    <br>

    <div class="img">
      <img src="Today.png" alt="Today" width="220">
      <p id="answer5">Quelle est la date?</p>
      <button type="button" onclick="document.getElementById('answer5').innerHTML = 'C&#8217;est '">
        Reveal answer</button>

    </div>

    <div class="img">
      <img src="Today.png" alt="Today" width="220">
      <p id="answer6">Quelle est le mot?</p>
    </div>

    <div class="img">
      <img src="Tomorrow.png" alt="Tomorrow" width="220">
      <p id="answer7">Quelle est la date?</p>
    </div>

    <div class="img">
      <img src="Tomorrow.png" alt="Tomorrow" width="220">
      <p id="answer8">Quelle est le mot?</p>
    </div>
  </center>
  <br>
  <br>
  <br>
  <br>
  <p>Date&#58;</p>
  <p id="date"></p>

  <script>
    var today = new Date()
    var day = today.getDay() + 1
    var dd = today.getDate()
    var mm = today.getMonth() + 1
    var yyyy = today.getFullYear()


    if (dd < 10) {
      dd = '0' + dd
    }

    if (mm < 10) {
      mm = '0' + mm
    }

    if (mm = 01) {
      mm = 'janvier'
    }
    if (mm = 02) {
      mm = 'février'
    }
    if (mm = 03) {
      mm = 'mars'
    }
    if (mm = 04) {
      mm = 'avril'
    }
    if (mm = 05) {
      mm = 'mai'
    }
    if (mm = 06) {
      mm = 'juin'
    }
    if (mm = 07) {
      mm = 'juillet'
    }
    if (mm = 08) {
      mm = 'août'
    }
    if (mm = 09) {
      mm = 'septembre'
    }
    if (mm = 10) {
      mm = 'octobre'
    }
    if (mm = 11) {
      mm = 'novembre'
    }
    if (mm = 12) {
      mm = 'décembre'
    }

    if (day = 1) {
      day = 'dimanche'
    }
    if (day = 2) {
      day = 'landi'
    }
    if (day = 3) {
      day = 'mardi'
    }
    if (day = 4) {
      day = 'mercredi'
    }
    if (day = 5) {
      day = 'jeudi'
    }
    if (day = 6) {
      day = 'vendridi'
    }
    if (day = 7) {
      day = 'samedi'
    }
    if (dd = 01) {
      dd = 'premier'
    }
    if (dd = 02) {
      dd = 'deux'
    }
    if (dd = 03) {
      dd = 'trois'
    }
    if (dd = 04) {
      dd = 'quatre'
    }
    if (dd = 05) {
      dd = 'cinq'
    }
    if (dd = 06) {
      dd = 'six'
    }
    if (dd = 07) {
      dd = 'sept'
    }
    if (dd = 08) {
      dd = 'huit'
    }
    if (dd = 09) {
      dd = 'neuf'
    }
    if (dd = 10) {
      dd = 'dix'
    }
    if (dd = 11) {
      dd = 'onze'
    }
    if (dd = 12) {
      dd = 'douze'
    }
    if (dd = 13) {
      dd = 'treize'
    }
    if (dd = 14) {
      dd = 'quatorze'
    }
    if (dd = 15) {
      dd = 'quinze'
    }
    if (dd = 16) {
      dd = 'seize'
    }
    if (dd = 17) {
      dd = 'dix&ndash;sept'
    }
    if (dd = 18) {
      dd = 'dix&ndash;huit'
    }
    if (dd = 19) {
      dd = 'dix&ndash;neuf'
    }
    if (dd = 20) {
      dd = 'vingt'
    }
    if (dd = 21) {
      dd = 'vingt&ndash;et&ndash;un'
    }
    if (dd = 22) {
      dd = 'vingt&ndash;deux'
    }
    if (dd = 23) {
      dd = 'vingt&ndash;trois'
    }
    if (dd = 24) {
      dd = 'vingt&ndash;quatre'
    }
    if (dd = 25) {
      dd = 'vingt&ndash;cinq'
    }
    if (dd = 26) {
      dd = 'vingt&ndash;six'
    }
    if (dd = 27) {
      dd = 'vingt&ndash;sept'
    }
    if (dd = 28) {
      dd = 'vingt&ndash;huit'
    }
    if (dd = 29) {
      dd = 'vignt&ndash;neuf'
    }
    if (dd = 30) {
      dd = 'trente'
    }
    if (dd = 31) {
      dd = 'trente&ndash;et&ndash;un'
    }

    document.getElementById("date").innerHTML = today = 'Aujourd&#8217;hui c&#8217;est ' + day + '&#44; le ' + dd + ' ' + mm + '&#44;' + yyyy;
  </script>
  </head>

  <body style="filter:progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Gradient(endColorstr='#FF6666', startColorstr='#FFFFFF', gradientType='0');">
  </body>

</html>
```

Comment: You must use == or ===

Comment: Why do you have so much html code in your header ? *<head></head>*

Comment: Inside all if statements, you are assigning, not comparing...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Javascript you have to do comparison with "==" or "==="

Your current if statements contain "=" which would be doing assignment and not comparison.

```
  <script>
    var today = new Date()
    var day = today.getDay() + 1
    var dd = today.getDate()
    var mm = today.getMonth() + 1
    var yyyy = today.getFullYear()


    if (dd < 10) {
      dd = '0' + dd
    }

    if (mm < 10) {
      mm = '0' + mm
    }

    if (mm == 01) {
      mm = 'janvier'
    }
    if (mm == 02) {
      mm = 'février'
    }
    if (mm == 03) {
      mm = 'mars'
    }
    if (mm == 04) {
      mm = 'avril'
    }
    if (mm == 05) {
      mm = 'mai'
    }
    if (mm == 06) {
      mm = 'juin'
    }
    if (mm == 07) {
      mm = 'juillet'
    }
    if (mm == 08) {
      mm = 'août'
    }
    if (mm == 09) {
      mm = 'septembre'
    }
    if (mm == 10) {
      mm = 'octobre'
    }
    if (mm == 11) {
      mm = 'novembre'
    }
    if (mm == 12) {
      mm = 'décembre'
    }

    if (day == 1) {
      day = 'dimanche'
    }
    if (day == 2) {
      day = 'landi'
    }
    if (day == 3) {
      day = 'mardi'
    }
    if (day == 4) {
      day = 'mercredi'
    }
    if (day == 5) {
      day = 'jeudi'
    }
    if (day == 6) {
      day = 'vendridi'
    }
    if (day == 7) {
      day = 'samedi'
    }
    if (dd == 01) {
      dd = 'premier'
    }
    if (dd == 02) {
      dd = 'deux'
    }
    if (dd == 03) {
      dd = 'trois'
    }
    if (dd == 04) {
      dd = 'quatre'
    }
    if (dd == 05) {
      dd = 'cinq'
    }
    if (dd == 06) {
      dd = 'six'
    }
    if (dd == 07) {
      dd = 'sept'
    }
    if (dd == 08) {
      dd = 'huit'
    }
    if (dd == 09) {
      dd = 'neuf'
    }
    if (dd == 10) {
      dd = 'dix'
    }
    if (dd == 11) {
      dd = 'onze'
    }
    if (dd == 12) {
      dd = 'douze'
    }
    if (dd == 13) {
      dd = 'treize'
    }
    if (dd == 14) {
      dd = 'quatorze'
    }
    if (dd == 15) {
      dd = 'quinze'
    }
    if (dd == 16) {
      dd = 'seize'
    }
    if (dd == 17) {
      dd = 'dix&ndash;sept'
    }
    if (dd == 18) {
      dd = 'dix&ndash;huit'
    }
    if (dd == 19) {
      dd = 'dix&ndash;neuf'
    }
    if (dd == 20) {
      dd = 'vingt'
    }
    if (dd == 21) {
      dd = 'vingt&ndash;et&ndash;un'
    }
    if (dd == 22) {
      dd = 'vingt&ndash;deux'
    }
    if (dd == 23) {
      dd = 'vingt&ndash;trois'
    }
    if (dd == 24) {
      dd = 'vingt&ndash;quatre'
    }
    if (dd == 25) {
      dd = 'vingt&ndash;cinq'
    }
    if (dd == 26) {
      dd = 'vingt&ndash;six'
    }
    if (dd == 27) {
      dd = 'vingt&ndash;sept'
    }
    if (dd == 28) {
      dd = 'vingt&ndash;huit'
    }
    if (dd == 29) {
      dd = 'vignt&ndash;neuf'
    }
    if (dd == 30) {
      dd = 'trente'
    }
    if (dd == 31) {
      dd = 'trente&ndash;et&ndash;un'
    }

    document.getElementById("date").innerHTML = today = 'Aujourd&#8217;hui c&#8217;est ' + day + '&#44; le ' + dd + ' ' + mm + '&#44;' + yyyy;
  </script>
```